# Need a text field that can be stylized by the user and stored in a database while taking into account paragraphs etc

Tags: php, mysql, html

How to have an editable text field like this, that you can make bold, insert paragraphs etc. The field is stored in a MySql databse and my website is html/php with some jquery. This would need to be used on a web interface. Im not sure what to search for even. I searched editable text field, txt field withparagraphs etc and havent found much. any help to just point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Just curious what to even search for.

Comment: Did you read the question? This person's question doesn't require posting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `wysiwyg html editor`

Comment: wow have heard that before but never thought of it! Thanks a bunch much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know if it is easy to simply upload that to an sql table? and will it simply hold the formatting? downloading one now! thanks again!

Comment: yes, most of them will have examples of the server code. This will help you get to know what all encoding/decoding you need to do before saving/fetching the data.